# R: Use apply correctly

Tags: r

I would like to create a simple code to join columns then count how many category variable has in my data frame. My problems is when I use `apply`, I get a right result but five times.

EXAMPLE:

```
a <- c('car','bike',NA,'moto','skate')
b <- c(NA,'car',NA,NA,'bike')
c <- c('car',NA,NA,'skate',NA)
d <- c('moto','skate',NA,'car',NA)

data <- data.frame(a,b,c,d)
```

then, using `apply`:

```
x <- vector('list',length = NCOL(data)*NROW(data))
one_column <- apply(data,1,function(y){
  x <- rbind(y,x)
  return(x)
})
```

Then `unlist` and use `table` for count how many categorical variables I have in my data:

```
one_column <- unlist(one_column)
table(one_column)
```

But for I get the right result I need divide by 5:

```
table(one_column)/5
```

Comment: Why not just use: `table(unlist(data))`???

Comment: Because I want practice  `apply`  function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `x` vector you created is 5 times larger than each column, so it's recycling the data. What you want is this instead.

```
x <- vector('list',length = NCOL(data))
```

Or, like emilliman5 says, just use `table(unlist(data))`.

Comment: `x <- vector('list',length = NROW(data))
one_column <- apply(data,1,function(y){
  x <- rbind(y,x)
  return(x)
})`


Warning messages:
1: In rbind(y, x) :
  number of columns of result is not a multiple of vector length (arg 1)

Comment: It needs to be length = NCOL(data), not length = NROW(data), because you're using apply on the rows.

Comment: Thanks, make sence